# Append data to JSON array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, append, push

I'm having issues in the code below trying to push data into a JSON structure that has an array. In the following code "M" is an array that can be added to, x is an integer value. I am trying to put a number of entries into the array "P" using push, but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
var x = 3;
var title = "A Title"
var JSON_local_dat = {"M":[{"T":title, "P":[]}]};

for(var i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    var d = {"Something": 50};
    JSON_local_dat.M.P.push(d);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON_local_dat.M.P));
}
```

I have also tried removing the double quotes but I get the same error.
If I instead try pushing the data into "M" it is successful, but not "P".
Can't see why it shouldn't do the same for P which is where I want the data to go.

(BTW I am using single letters as names because space is tight, the API I am using to pass the data to is limiting me to 4000 characters.)

Answer (score 0):

`M` is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Use `M[0]` to get the first entry in array which here happens to be an object with property `P`.

```js
x = 3;
var JSON_local_dat = {"M":[{"T":"title", "P":[]}]};

for(var i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    var d = {"Something": 50};
    JSON_local_dat.M[0].P.push(d);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON_local_dat.M[0].P));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I became code blind! The answer is obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

`P` is a property of the *first object in the `M` array*, not of `M` itself. You need to select the first item of the array to get to the object (and not the array itself) in order to access `P`:

```js
var x = 3;
var title = "A Title"
var JSON_local_dat = {"M":[{"T":title, "P":[]}]};

for(var i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    var d = {"Something": 50};
    JSON_local_dat.M[0].P.push(d);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON_local_dat.M));
```

If you wanted to make it more efficient, you might select the `P` array only once, rather than on every iteration:

```js
var x = 3;
var title = "A Title"
var P = [];
var JSON_local_dat = {"M":[{"T":title, P}]};


for(var i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    var d = {"Something": 50};
    P.push(d);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON_local_dat.M));
```

Also, you do not have JSON there - you just have a plain Javascript object. See [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Your json (JSON_local_dat) is not build the way you want. you made M to be an array (that its first element has P property).
change to -

```
var JSON_local_dat = {"M":{"T":title, "P":[]}};
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, use `M[0]` since its an array.

`JSON_local_dat.M[0].P.push(d);`